Getting java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown level constant [8] error while deploying .ear in wildfly container, in a running K8s environment
I am trying to deploy .ear in my running k8s setup and i'm getting the following error
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown level constant [8].
        at deployment.platform_sec.ear//org.apache.logging.log4j.Level.valueOf(Level.java:320)
        at deployment.platform_sec.ear//org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.setToDefault(AbstractConfiguration.java:725)
        at deployment.platform_sec.ear//org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.DefaultConfiguration.<init>(DefaultConfiguration.java:47)
        at deployment.platform_sec.ear//org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.<init>(LoggerContext.java:95)
        at deployment.platform_sec.ear//org.apache.logging.log4j.core.selector.ClassLoaderContextSelector.createContext(ClassLoaderContextSelector.java:254)
        at deployment.platform_sec.ear//org.apache.logging.log4j.core.selector.ClassLoaderContextSelector.locateContext(ClassLoaderContextSelector.java:218)
        at deployment.platform_sec.ear//org.apache.logging.log4j.core.selector.ClassLoaderContextSelector.getContext(ClassLoaderContextSelector.java:136)
        at deployment.platform_sec.ear//org.apache.logging.log4j.core.selector.ClassLoaderContextSelector.getContext(ClassLoaderContextSelector.java:123)
        at deployment.platform_sec.ear//org.apache.logging.log4j.core.selector.ClassLoaderContextSelector.getContext(ClassLoaderContextSelector.java:117)
        at deployment.platform_sec.ear//org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:150)
        at deployment.platform_sec.ear//org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:47)
        at deployment.platform_sec.ear//org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getContext(LogManager.java:196)
        at deployment.platform_sec.ear//org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getLogger(LogManager.java:599)

But if i create a docker image and apply that in my k8s setup, then i don't get any such error. I am using Log4j2.xml for configuration, Wildfly 20.0.0 final and Log4j version 2.16.0.
I tried exluding the subystem logging in jboss-deployment-structure.xml, but the error did not resolve.Here is the link to log4j.xml file https://drive.google.com/file/d/1n8AZnC0bGDLva3L9pzub9SZ7YKhvb2m8/view?usp=drive_link

Please add your configuration file and all the Java system properties that start with log4j. or similar to your question. Your probably set the value of log4j2.level or similar to 8 instead of a valid level.

Thanks for the reply, i have added the log4j.xml file's link.

WildFly 20 does not include integration for log4j2 so excluding the logging subsystem won't do any good. I'd check the dependencies in your deployment as something is trying to use a level of "8".
